# Why doesn't htmlagilitypack include attribute when creating a new node?

Tags: .net, html-agility-pack

using .Net and htmlagilitypack. Trying to put outer tag on a node as such ('item' in the loop is the one of the found 'section' tags):

```
<section aria-label="Tables">...</section>

        foreach (var item in extraTags.ToList())
        {
            var newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<oTag class='cCls'>" + item.OuterHtml + "</oTag>");
            item.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, item);
        }
```

So I would expect the new node to look like:

```
<oTag class='cCls'><section aria-label="Tables">...</section></oTag>
```

but instead I get:

```
<oTag class='cCls'><section>...</section></oTag>
```

it leaves out the 'aria-label="Tables"' part. How come? and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works with me, can you double check ?

```
    var doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(@"
        <section aria-label='Tables'>
            Text
        </section>
    ");
    var section = doc.DocumentNode.Element("section");
    var newNode = HtmlNode.CreateNode("<oTag class='cCls'>" + section.OuterHtml + "</oTag>");
    section.ParentNode.ReplaceChild(newNode, section);

    Console.WriteLine(doc.DocumentNode.OuterHtml);
```